# Internals of the Object constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Reading the Rails guides, I notice that the actual Object constant stores a table.

> First, when the module keyword is processed, the interpreter creates a
>   new entry in the constant table of the class object stored in the
>   Object constant. Said entry associates the name "Colors" to a newly
>   created module object. Furthermore, the interpreter sets the name of
>   the new module object to be the string "Colors"

However when I try to access Object  it just returns

```
=> Object
```

Is there a way to access the internals of the Object constant in Ruby? And perhaps get a glimpse of the table with said `Module-object-to-name`
mappings.

Comment: what about `Module.constants` ? have you try this

Comment: Oh nice. write an answer, i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Module.constants  # ==> All constants`  may help you.